# Window.whatever is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have some code that is running correctly but occasionally Muscula reports an error that `whatever is undefined`. Why is it reporting this?

```js
window.whatever = function(jQuery) {
  var obj = {
    content: function() {
      return this
    },
    inject: function(passwordUrl) {
      return this
    }
  };

  return obj;
}

jQuery(function() {
  window.whatever(jQuery).inject("foo.html").content();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also available as a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7a350syq/

Comment: the code that you have provided will never throw the error you're reporting. if you don't give us the correct code to duplicate the problem then no one is going to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Your code in fiddle looks valid and works as expected. Are you sure you have an issue in it?

Comment: here's a tip though: if something is happening *occasionally* it means it's probably a race condition.

Comment: Thanks @Iwrestledabearonce and Sergey. This is the part of the code that I suspect  is the culprit but it is part of a large project so thought I would start here. I agree that it is probably a race condition issue. The project has many different versions of jQuery that load in differing orders.

Comment: "The project has many different versions of jQuery that load in differing orders." - You should fix that. That will cause problems.

Comment: Thanks @JamesGould, I could not agree more. The entire site is being less than a year so it's something we have to support in the meantime.